# Crypto sign string using DSA private key in Salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, security, crypto, lightning-container

Colleagues,
I'm doing integration using REST API with a service that requires a string signed by private key which uses DSA algorithm.
The problem is in APEX Crypto class does not support DSA keys (only RSA supported).

I tried to use this JS library: https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/
but it seems like i'm unable to use it in lightning (KJUR is not defined).
Basically i've imported library to static resource and used ltng:require to load into lightning component.

I was also thinking about lightning:container, but i'm not sure if this will work with this library.

Maybe some of you had any experience to integrate apps using DSA keys in Salesforce? Any recommendation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) key?